# How to use Adapter to access views in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to use some methods on this switch which is within a RecyclerView. I want to use methods like mSwitch.setEnabled(true) in the MainActivity:  
[image]

how do I do this? Please help! I'm new to android and the sad part, I haven't subscribed any android course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you click on child views like this in recyclerView from recyclerViewAdapter

```
    viewHolder.switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // do something, the isChecked will be
        // true if the switch is in the On position
    }
});
```

Comment: So i should paste this in the MainActivity?

Comment: in recyclerView adapter